# Update logout time and duration

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am using ASP.NET and want to calculate the difference between two times. Actually, I had a scenario to calculate the difference between the login and logout times.

For example, in organizations there is some particular limit for working hours. So if a user logs in at 9:00 AM in the morning and logs out at 5:00 PM in the evening, we need to calculate how much duration he stayed in the office (which is 8 hours in the present scenario ).

But I want to do this in ASP.NET. I calculate the duration between the two times but the problem is that:

- if the first day I log in at 09:10:15 and log out at 17:20:55, the duration time is 08:10:40
- if the second say I log in at 09:00:00  and log out at 10:50:20, the duration time is 01:50:20

The first day logout time and duration time is also updated. That means that the first day logout time takes the second day logout time (i.e. 10:50:20).

How to do this correctly?

Comment: I would suggest you re-read your question and improve the formatting, content and grammar. Also add some sample code that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't store only time but date and operations type and find previous record on logout.
 When it login type record You can calculate difference otherwise abnormal situation.
 So on login - if previous record type is *login* - abnormal.

What You should do in abnormal situation depends on You.

But if you use web technology You must understand what user can never logout.